# Microsoft graph migration- Events

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

I am trying to migrate existing code to Microsoft graph-based API. In the existing flow, we are getting
"`ICalRecurrenceId`" -

As per definition, The "RECURRENCE-ID" property is used in conjunction with the "UID" and "SEQUENCE" properties to identify a particular instance of a recurring event, to-do, or journal. For a given pair of "UID" and "SEQUENCE" property values, the "RECURRENCE-ID" value for a recurrence instance is fixed.

Can anyone tell me which field in graph API would map to ICalRecurrenceId?

Answer (score 0):

The Graph API `event` resource type describes the event in a user or group calendar. The event has a property `iCalUId` which is a unique identifier for an event across calendars and is different for each occurence in a recurring series. Please see here for additional documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0